# Model order reduction - Criag Bampton method

Tags: mechanical-engineering, finite-element-method

I am trying to understand how model reduction works, more specifically the Criag Bampton method. I would like to implement this method on a simple model in Python. I have been reading the following resources:

1. [Original article](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01537654/file/RCMB.pdf)
2. [Code aster documentation](https://biba1632.gitlab.io/code-aster-manuals/docs/reference/r4.06.02.html)
3. [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_substructuring)
4. [Some more papers](https://scholarship.rice.edu/bitstream/handle/1911/102299/Interface_Reduction_Methods_for_HCB_models.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y)
5. [And not only...](https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/1568976)

The reduction of sub-structures is clear and I can get the same results. What I don't understand is how to:

- Assemble the whole matrix by satisfying the compatibility condition and the equilibrium condition (definitions in ref 3).

Example: in ref 4 eq (9) how was that matrix defined and how can this guarantee both conditions (compatibility and equilibrium). The same for ref 5 eq (24-25).

Do you have a simple example to illustrate this procedure? Do you know of a good resource that explains how this is done?

Comment: One way to see what's going on is to go to 1D.  Take two 1D bars (1 element each) and join them at the common node.  Then work out all the matrices.  Once that's clear, go to 2D (two plane stress quads that share two nodes) and repeat the process.  The notation should become clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'll try that... For the moment with a first look I don't really see how to do it when using modal coordinates for the sub-elements